# Creating a drag hint using a div

Tags: html, css

In the following plunk, I've created a div element to be used as a drag `hint`. It's initially `hidden`, then made `visible` in the `drag` event of a Kendo treeview.
 [drag hint plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/55MdA3NajWtNYUIYNXGr?p=preview)

In the plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/55MdA3NajWtNYUIYNXGr?p=preview, you can simply expand a treeview node and start to drag it downward towards the Kendo grid below.

My question is: how can I make the "DROP RISK MEASURE HERE" text a bit dark while the outer div still has `opacity: .3` ? I really don't want to create another div outside of this just to have the text bolder.

thank you,

Bob

ex/

```css
.drop-zone {
        color:crimson;
        visibility: hidden;
        border: 2px dashed;
        background-color: seashell;
        height: 200px;
        width: 720px;
        top: 400px;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: .3;
        z-index:10;
    }
    .drop-text {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: crimson;
        text-align:center;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="dropAreaDimen" class="drop-zone">
  <div class="drop-text">DROP RISK MEASURE HERE..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just fade out the background and keep the text at its exact opacity value.

First remove the line

```
background-color: seashell;
```

from `.drop-zone` class's style

And add this line instead

```
background-color:rgba(245,255,238,0.3);
```

Comment: Okay, so you're using rgba(), where the 4th parameter is the opacity ! I see.